# Mandarin version of 剩翻 (left over)?

Tags: grammar, cantonese

In Cantonese 剩翻 often means left over or surplus, as in 剩翻好少錢 （only a little money remains) or 剩翻好多飯 （lots of rice/food left over). What's the Mandarin equivalent of 剩翻? Would it be 留下？

CantoDict page: http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/48306/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

剩翻 can also be written as 剩番

**广州话方言词典**

> 剩下；只剩
>
> 剩番兩個
>
> 剩番地理未考完。
>
> 只剩地理還沒考完。

《广州话-普通话》

> 留下；剩下
>
> 剩番佢兩個喺度值班
>
> 留下他兩個值班
>
> 份稿剩番幾頁未抄。
>
> 稿子剩下幾頁沒有抄完

Here we have 剩下, 留下 and 只剩 all used in different translations of 剩番 or 剩翻.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Cantonese, but based on your description, I believe the appropriate translation for Mandarin would be 剩下.